# Negative number to positive number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script that I tried, based off of other scripts, but it isn't doing anything. It says it completes without any errors, but the data is unchanged.

I am trying to change the values in column C to a positive vale by multiplying by -1.
This range changes as data is added at the bottom of the list, and that is why I a looking for the last row. I am assuming that is probably the problem but I am unsure at this point.

```
function neg2Pos() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Import');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,3, lastRow - 1, 1);
  var value = range.getValue();
 
  if(lastRow != 1 && sheet == "Import"){
    range.setValue(value * - 1)
  }
```

I wanted to try before asking for help. I thought this should work.

Comment: square all numbers, then take square root... if positive at start they stay positive, if negative they become positive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some more looking and using ideas from another App Script that I have, I was able to get this to work:

```
function removNeg(){
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Import');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,3, lastRow, 1)
  var values = range.getValues();
  var absValues = values.map(([r]) => [!r || isNaN(r) ? r : Math.abs(r)]);
  range.setValues(absValues);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function neg2Pos() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 3, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  let o = vs.map(e => {
    if (e < 0) {
      return [-1 * e]
    } else {
      return [e];
    }
  });
    sh.getRange(2,3,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
  }
```